# tar and if-statement

Tags: files, scripting, ksh, tar

I have a script that check if a file exist inside a tar file but something's wrong because it always go to the `else` part of the script. I am pretty sure that it shouldn't be that way.

The date is in "Mon dd" format (Jan 11).

```sh
echo "enter date: \c"
read date
tarfile=`tar -tvf tarfile.tar | grep some_file | grep "$date"`

if [ -f "$tarfile" ]; then
    echo "yes"
    else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're checking if the file exists by using `-f`, but that's not what you want to do. The file exists in the tar file, but `-f` has no way of reading inside tar archives by itself. For example, if your file is at "foo/bar" inside the tar file, it will look for "foo/bar" relative your current directory, which doesn't exist.

The better way is to just check the exit status of `grep`, instead of trying to parse the output.

```sh
printf 'enter date: '
read date
if tar -tvf tarfile.tar | grep some_file | grep -q "$date"; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```